# Python pandas concatenate columns csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation

I have a huge list of `Users_id` that I want to concatenate.  I know how to do it in excel but the file is much too large.

```
Users ID    
101 101
102 101,102
103 101,102,103
104 101,102,103,104
```

Here is what I want to achieve. Here is what I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

pd.concat = df['USER ID']=.astype(str)+','+df['USER ID']
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual operation since your input is numeric, while your output is a sequence of comma-separated strings. One solution is to use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) with f-strings (Python 3.6; [PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import accumulate

df = pd.DataFrame({'Users': [101, 102, 103, 104]})

def joiner(x, y):
    return f'{x},{y}'

df['Cumulative'] = list(accumulate(df['Users'].astype(str), func=joiner))

print(df)

   Users       Cumulative
0    101              101
1    102          101,102
2    103      101,102,103
3    104  101,102,103,104
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code.
If you want to concatenate all the user ids, you should iterate over the ID column and concatenate manually all the id. The following code should do so

```
id_column=df['ID']
all_ids=''
for id in id_column:
    all_ids+=str(id)+','
```

All the IDs should be contained in variable all_ids.

Comment: If this is what OP wants, then `','.join(df['ID'].astype(str))` is sufficient.